# Is it possible to use the gift library to view all of the branches of a remote repository?

Tags: git, node.js, grit, gift

[Gift](https://github.com/notatestuser/gift) is a `node.js` library that implements `grit` like functionality. To view remote branches, ordinarly I would do `git branch -r`, but I don't see any such functionality in the `gift` package.

Is it possible, using `gift`, to view all of the remote branches of a git repository and pull them down?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not currently (November 2013): it is still an active project, and it doesn't include any:

- `git branch -r`, or
- `git ls-remote`

That leaves you with the option to implement it (a bit like [`git remote` was implemented](https://github.com/notatestuser/gift/commit/d6cf520009755c30b1ec59663f64f060dc74cca0)), and propose a pull request.